# Decode this message to stop the destruction of Science!

Tags: mathematics, cipher, algebra

An extremist religious organization called "The Redeemed Against Scientific Usurpation of God's Authority", or RASUGA, have converted the world's leading time travel researcher to their beliefs. Using his credentials, he assisted RASUGA in stealing his time machine from his lab at the CERN facility in Meyrin, Switzerland.

Before they were discovered and killed, our moles in RASUGA were able to uncover their plan: they intend to use the time maching to travel to 1699 and murder Sir Isaac Newton and Gottfried Leibniz before they could discover and publish their results in physics and calculus. They believe this would be sufficient for setting back scientific advancement for hundreds of years.

WE MUST STOP THEM.

Our spies have intercepted the following message from a high ranking RASUGA priest:

> djzyzlbbzjt anctdpclzdapzfe
>
> cbasazb adf aizdbkals
>
> bkdpejdpasbdzuzjn

We believe this message contains the location of the stolen time machine. Can you decode the message and save science?

As our spies intercept more messages we will add them.

Hint #1:

> Our spies have uncovered another facet of their plan. We believe that the work of Newton and Leibnitz may be integral to decoding the cipher, and that by going back in time and killing them, it will erase the evidence of this plan by leaving their messages indecipherable.

Hint #2:

> Our spies have indicated that the original recipients are having trouble deciphering the message. We have intercepted a second message that we believe is integral to interpreting the message. (In bold) it reads: **There are no constants in our message, but we have redeemed this heresy for our purposes:** $$\int\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i x^{n-i}}dx=\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{c_i x^{n-i+1}}{n-i+1}}$$ **-Matt. 20:16a**

Hint #3:

> We've intercepted another transmission, and it appears they have re-sent the original message with some annotations:
>  $dj^5zy^4zl^3bb^2zj^1t^0\,\,$ $an^7ct^6dp^5cl^4zd^3ap^2zf^1e^0$
>  $cb^3as^2az^1b^0\,\,$ $ad^1f^0\,\,$ $ai^4zd^3bk^2al^1s^0$
>  $bk^8dp^7ej^6dp^5as^4bd^3zu^2zj^1n^0$

Hint #4:

> It is of great advantage to us that RASUGA's agents have villified mathematics - their agents cannot solve their mathematical cipher! They have sent another transmission, this time giving the solution to one of the words in the cipher: *adf*=**of**. We hope this will be enough for our analysts to decipher the message.

Hint #5:

> As we initially suspected the simple A1Z26 cipher is involved. As the annotated message lists many of the letters in pairs, we believe the first letter of a pair gives the number of cycles through the alphabet and the second letter gives a remainder.

Comment: There isn't a $dx$ in the left side of the equality of hint 2?

Comment: Nice catch. I had a professor at uni who had a bad habit of never writing dx when the variable of integration was unambiguous.

Comment: I tried to produce a decoding function, and it produces some Chinese characters. Does this have something to do with Chinese?

Comment: No. The original message is in English.

Comment: Is #2 supposed to be a geometric series? This might be helpful

Comment: Using a rot13(cbylnycunorgvp/Ivtarer pvcure) might help, but so far it does not seem to yield anything. By the way, Matthew 20:16 in the Bible says: "So the last will be first, and the first will be last.”.